# how to parse a CSV file with C++ that has no clear formatting style

Tags: c++, csv, parsing

Ive been tearing my hair out over parsing through a CSV file that has almost no consistent formatting and constantly breaks any convention that a CSV file would typically entail.

my issue is that even when utilizing a CSV parser or attempting to write a parser specific to my issue i run into the problem of the raw data in the CSV is essentially just a significant amount of characters occasionally delimited by commas which wouldnt cause any issue if it werent for the fact that within the data fields delimited by commas there are numerous cases of extraneous commas, and without any form of consistent structure or format to the data ive been struggling to find a way to properly distinguish the "CSV Commas" from commas simply held within data fields.

Ive looked through the documentation for a handful of CSV parsers that were linked to in answers to other CSV related questions on SO but it doesnt seem as though they could handle the issue as they are all expecting more consistent format to the data being input. Any help at all or even a finger pointed in a helpful direction would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Let me guess. Medical dataset?

Comment: If your input is garbage, then using a conventional CSV parsing library, that expects all input to be well-formed, obviously won't work. You'll have to roll-your-own, heuristically-based parser, that tries to turn crap into candy.

Comment: You really hate commas and apostrophes, don't you?

Comment: With those ifs you do not have a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV format requires that a field that contains commas is quoted. For example:

```
 123,"one,two,three"
```

It's not hard to write a parser to deal with this, and any half-decent CSV library should support it out of the box, along with dealing with the issue of embedded double-quotes.

What no library can easily support is some arbitrary commas such as this:

```
 123,one,two,three
```

where the last two commas are really intended to be part of a second field (and hence is not really CSV). You would need to write your own parser and/or have some way of describing the non-CSV data.